# configure an odbcdatasource in visual studio for a querystring to mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

hi im trying to configure an odbcdatasource in visual studio, I have the connection string in my web.config file and I can see it but im trying to configure the datasource for a custom sql query string so I can query to mysql

```
SELECT FirstName, SecondName FROM User WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + ? + '%'
```

and then set the params for the odbcdatasource to

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="FirstName" QueryStringField="TextBox1.Text" 
        Type="String" />
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is correct, I have never used it like this atleast.
a Querystring is a part of a url, meaning if your url would be:
home.aspx?firstname=Garrith

you would have the following:

```
        <SelectParameters>
          <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="qsFirstName" QueryStringField="firstname" />
        </SelectParameters>

SELECT FirstName, SecondName FROM User WHERE FirstName LIKE '%' + @qsFirstName + '%'
```

If you are looking to use it from a textbox id, I would suggest doing it on codebehind,
and make something like:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     string FirstName = Textbox1.Text;
     odbcdatasource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT FirstName, SecondName FROM User WHERE FirstName LIKE '%" + FirstName + "%'";

     Gridview1.DataBind()
// (Gridview1 = your element id)
}
```

Lauw

Comment: can you do ListView.DataBind?

Comment: Yes just checked it and it does have that command available, so should work the same.

Comment: even with gridview i cant get this to work nothing is displayed in the gridview

Comment: Have you checked if your query works? try putting a breakpoint at the selectcommand and take the query and run it at the database directly